# How to update State Hook with onClick listener on React Component Instance

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-props, use-state

I'm attempting to add an onClick to a component instance which changes the state of a useState hook, and prints it out to the console. However, nothing fires when the component instance is clicked.

I have tried wrapping it in a JSX div element and adding an onClick to the div which works in printing to the console, but the state is not updated as always shows an undefined.

The end goal is to pass the state to another component (Linked page) after click.

Here is my code.

**Card.js**

```
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card" style={{ background: `${props.background}` }}>
      <h2>{props.taskName}</h2>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import "../pages/Home.scss";
import ProfileButton from "../components/ProfileButton";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import "./PlayerPage";

export default function Home() {
  const date = new Date();
  const time = date.getHours();
  let timeOfDay;

  if (time < 12) {
    timeOfDay = "Morning";
  } else if (time >= 12 && time < 6) {
    timeOfDay = "Afternoon";
  } else {
    timeOfDay = "Evening";
  }

  const [task, setTask] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(task);
  })

 return (
  <>
   <Header />
    <main className="home-main">
     <div className="main-wrap">
      <section className="card-container">
       <h1>Good {timeOfDay}</h1>
        <h1>Choose Your Work Style</h1>

         <div className="card-wrap">
          <Link to="/PlayerPage">
           <Card onClick={() => {console.log("hey") }}
            taskName="Short Task"
            description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
         />
          </Link>
     </div>
</>
);
}
```

**PlayerPage.js - (Component which needs to display updated state)**

```
export default function PlayerPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="player-page-main">
        <div className="player-page-main-wrap">
          <div className="timer-title-wrap">
            <Timer />
            <h2 className="task-title">{Updated state here}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What in the `Card` component do you want to respond to being clicked?

Comment: As per the chosen answer, the card component is now clickable. However, state still doesn't update

Comment: It's unclear how you are validating the state update. Can you update your question to include a complete `Home` component so we can see the state and how `Card` is rendered? I see the state update in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-update-state-hook-with-onclick-listener-on-react-component-instance-wodjd). Oh I see, you are wanting to pass the `task` state on to `PlayerPage` component? What routing/navigation library are you using? I think this new issue is enough off-topic from this one it warrants a new stackoverflow post.

Comment: I'm using BrowserRouter & I agree. Will make a new post. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Feel free to ping (@) me here with a link to the new post, or ping (@) me in a comment in the new post, and I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: @DrewReese Here is the link to new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233178/browserrouter-link-overriding-onclick-event Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Card` component needs to attach the passed `onClick` handler prop to a DOM element.

Example:

```
export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{ background: `${props.background}` }}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      <h2>{props.taskName}</h2>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh I see why this makes sense now. Thanks so much.