# BrowserRouter Link overriding onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, use-effect

I'm attempting to update a State Hook after a click event. However, the BrowserRouter's Link around my component instance is overriding its onClick function.

But when I remove the 'Link To', the state successfully updates and prints in the console.

Eventually, I want to be able to pass the updated state to the PlayerPage component. But I'm using the console to test its updates for now - which it doesn't.

**Here is my code:**

**Home.js - Contains click event.**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  
const [task, setTask] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(task);
  },[task])

  return (
    <>
     <Header />
      <main className="home-main">
       <div className="main-wrap">
        <section className="card-container">
         <h1>Good Morning</h1>
           <h1>Choose Your Work Style</h1>

            <div className="card-wrap">
              <Link to="/PlayerPage">
                  <Card onClick={() => {setTask('Short Task')}}
                    taskName="Short Task"
                    description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
                  />
              </Link>
            </div>
   </>
 );
}
```

**PlayerPage.js - The destination of Link**

```
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Timer from "../components/Timer";
import "./PlayerPage.scss";

export default function PlayerPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className="player-page-main">
        <div className="player-page-main-wrap">
          <div className="timer-title-wrap">
            <Timer />
            <h2 className="task-title">{Task Name Will Go Here}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is what I was thinking was the case.

The click event is propagating to the `Link` component, so you could call `event.stopPropagation()` to keep the click event from bubbling, but now the link won't work.

If you use both then the link doesn't wait for the state to update.

I think the best option is to ***not*** use any local state and pass the data in route state in the link. Use the object version of the `to` prop to specify the `pathname` and route `state` for the navigation transition.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/PlayerPage",
          state: {
            task: 'Short Task',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Card
          taskName="Short Task"
          description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        />
      </Link>
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Then access the route state from the `location` object in the receiving component.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function PlayerPage() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      ...
        <h2 className="task-title">{state.task}</h2>
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/PlayerPage", state: { task } }} />
```

Insite your PlayerPage component your task value is accessible from the location prop.

```
this.props.location.state.data
```